# Intellij idea won't recognize import of local class in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, import

I've got a python3 script, script.py, and in it I want to instantiate a class Foobar which is defined in clazz.py. However, when I try to import, I get:

```
$ python3 script.py
...
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Here is my file structure:

```
python_import/
├── __init__.py
├── clazz.py
└── script.py
```

clazz.py:

```
class Foobar():
    def __init__(self):
        print("initialized a foobar")
```

script.py:

```
from .clazz import Foobar
foobar = Foobar()
```

It runs fine if I get rid of the `.` in the `import`; however, if I do this, my IDE (Intellij IDEA) red-underlines the import and won't autocomplete anything. I believe including the `.` is correct in python3, and Intellij seems to like it, so why won't my program run unless I remove it?

I have read http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#import, http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/import.html, [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory), [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) and [Relative import in Python 3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637428/relative-import-in-python-3-not-working).

I suspect it may have something to do with the virtualenv but a) I don't understand why the working directory wouldn't be part of the PYTHONPATH and b) I'm not really sure how to change it in virtualenv - Intellij set it up for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your IDE likes `.` is that it knows your script is in package `python_import/`, but when you run it through commandline, the interpreter knows nothing about package, so relative import won't work.

To eliminate the red line error of "unresolved reference", see [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm), it has perfect illustration step by step.