# Creating a package with several sub-packages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, package

I am trying to create a package in Python that has a number of sub-packages (I'm not sure if that's the right term for them) which need to interoperate.

I have a (simplified) structure like this:

```
/package
    |-script1.py
    |-script2.py
    |-subpackage1
    |   |-__init__.py
    |   |-src
    |   |   |-__init__.py
    |   |   |-my_program.py
    |   |   |-functions.py
    |   |   |-...
    |
    |-tests
    |    |-a_tests.py
    |-subpackage2
    |    |-web-server.py
    |    |-API
    |    |    |-__init__.py
    |    |    |-REST.py
    |    |    |-...
```

- `package/subpackage2` needs to be able to call `package/subpackage1/src/functions.py`
- `package/tests` calls both subpackages (using `pytests`).
- `package/subpackage1/src/functions.py` needs to be able to call other modules within `subpackage1`

I've seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33195094 - which explains what I need to do (create a package), but it doesn't explain *how* to do it.

I can readily get the two `scripts` to call their component sub-packages using:

`import subpackage1.src.my_program.py`

(i.e. similar to the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module)) but then `my_program.py` fails with an `ImportError: No module named 'functions'`

So, what glue do I need to set this structure up?

Comment: the `subpackage1` has to have a `__init__.py` be to detected as module. you added `__init__.py` in `src` but didnt in the `subpackage1`.

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI - Thanks. I've intermittently had one in there but wasn't sure if it was necessary. Having one in there doesn't seem to change anything; so some other stuff is needed to...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to import something from `functions.py` into `my_program.py` then in `my_program.py` you have to specify the absolute import path.

Let's say that `functions.py` contains following function:

```
def function1():
  print('foo bar')
```

Then, to import `function1` from `functions.py` into `my_program.py` its contents should look like:

```
from subpackage1.src.functions import function1

function1()
```

Comment: But can I tried `import subpackage1.src.functions` and do `functions.function1()`? It doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 3):

So to solve this issue i Created a similar folder structure

```
/package
    |-script1.py
    |-subpackage1
    |   |-__init__.py
    |   |-src
    |   |   |-__init__.py
    |   |   |-functions.py
```

my script1.py file has

```
import subpackage1
import subpackage1.src
import subpackage1.src.functions as f


print(f.hello())
```

my `functions.py` file has

```
def hello():
    return "from the functions"
```

now from the `package` folder

i did

`$ python script1.py`

the script ran and output

`from the functions`

showed.

I am using `python3`

So am i missing something because its working on my system.

Note: i added three different `imports` to check for import errors there.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import subpackage1.src.functions as f` in your `my_program.py`

When you run the module, stand in `package` folder and run as below:

`python -m subpackage1.src.my_program`